# Accessing Django Admin with requests library

Tags: django, django-admin, python-requests

I'm trying to access to my Django Admin through [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.

1. `r1 = requests.get('page.com/admin/')`
2. `r_token = r.cookies['csrftoken']`
3. `req_cookies = {'csrftoken': '{}'.format(r_token)}` # Cookie for the request
4. `req_data = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{}'.format(r_token),'username':'my_username','password':'my_password'}` # Data for request
5. `res = requests.post('page.com/admin/', cookies=req_cookies, data=req_data)`

At this point, I should have accessed to my admin page but it keeps asking for my credentials. Any idea?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `requests.post()` for the second request?

Comment: @knbk error while copy&pasting. sorry

Comment: Why don't you post your real code please? You are now posting to an invalid url

Comment: @e4c5 It's the usual django admin page.

Comment: not it isn't it's a localpage on your computer called page.com/admin and it requests will produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

The admin login page is `/admin/login/`. If you post to `/admin/` you'll get redirected to `/admin/login/`.

Comment: thanks but was a typo. Using the slash at the end don't fix the issue.

Comment: It looks like you should be posting to `/admin/login/`, not `/admin/`.